# Is there a C++ way to format addresses and pointers with iostream?

Tags: c++, iostream

I have something like

```
unsigned x = 16;
unsigned* p = &x;

std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(16) << std::setfill('0') << x << std::endl;
std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(16) << std::setfill('0') << p << std::endl;
```

output:

```
0000000000000010
000x7fffc35ba784
```

ostream::operator<< is overloaded for this? I can write this correctly with C, but I was wondering if there is a proper way to do this with iostream.

Comment: What’s your question? This seems to work … (but just outputting the pointer directly works as well).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is "how do I print a pointer with 16 hex digits".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `internal` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    unsigned x = 16;
    unsigned* p = &x;

    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(16) << std::setfill('0') << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(16) << std::setfill('0') << p << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::internal << std::hex << std::setw(16) << std::setfill('0') << p << std::endl;
}
```

This gives:

```
0000000000000010
000x7fffd123c1a4
0x007fffd123c1a4
```

Comment: The width is not correct. Use `setw(sizeof(p)*2+2)` to account for the leading `0x` instead.

Comment: @IInspectable: That obviously depends on what you want to achieve. But yes, if you want to guarantee all digits fit all the time, that would be the thing to do. However, I think the question was "how to get the zeros on the inside of the `0x` rather than in front, not "how do I calculate the right width for my pointer output".

Comment: I see solutions like this and I sometimes think maybe `sprintf` isn't so bad :)

Comment: haha, I was going in that direction, but I'm trying to use more c++

Comment: @Albert Streams are a poor abstraction in C++. If you want type safety and (semi)readable code you might want to consider using [The Boost Format library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/).

Comment: Note that my answer is not trying to promote/suggest that `stream` is a good solution. Just trying to answer the actual question asked. I do often suggest alternatives, etc. For a lot of things, streams are actually fairly easy to use (and definitely more type-safe than `printf\scanf`).